# R: transforming specific rows into columns

Tags: json, r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I have quite messy data imported from json file, it looks like this:

```
raw_df <- data.frame(text = c(paste0('text', 1:3), '---------- OUTCOME LINE ----------', paste0('text', 4:6), '---------- OUTCOME LINE ----------'),
                              demand = c('cat1', rep('', 2), 'info', 'cat2', rep('', 2), 'info2')
                     )



raw_df
                                text demand
1                              text1   cat1
2                              text2       
3                              text3       
4 ---------- OUTCOME LINE ----------   info
5                              text4   cat2
6                              text5       
7                              text6       
8 ---------- OUTCOME LINE ----------  info2
```

(BTW, `---------- OUTCOME LINE ----------` is the actual string that I have in `text` column)

I want to tidy it up so that it has the following format:

```
final_df
                  text demand outcome
1 text1. text2. text3.   cat1   info1
2 text4. text5. text6.   cat2   info2
```

What would be the quickest and most efficient way to do this? thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we create a logical index using 'grepl' based on the presence of `-` in the 'text' column, subset the 'raw_df' to remove those rows, create a grouping column by getting cumulative sum of 'indx', `aggregate` to `paste` the 'text' column grouped by 'demand' after replacing the `''` with `NA` and using `na.locf` to fill the non-NA previous values.  Then, create the 'outcome' from the 'demand' by subsetting with 'indx'

```
indx <- grepl("-", raw_df$text)
transform(aggregate(text~demand, transform(raw_df[!indx,], 
  demand = zoo::na.locf(replace(demand, demand=="", NA))), toString),
    outcome = raw_df$demand[indx])
#  demand                text outcome
#1   cat1 text1, text2, text3    info
#2   cat2 text4, text5, text6   info2
```

---

Or this can be done with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(raw_df)[demand == "", demand := NA][!indx, .(text= paste(text, collapse='. ')),
          .(demand = zoo::na.locf(demand))][, outcome := raw_df$demand[indx]][]
```

Comment: Both solutions work great, thanks for that! However, `toString` uses comma as a separator between text fields, is there a way to change it to full stop?

Comment: @KasiaKulma  Sorry, I thought it wouldn't matter, you can use `text= paste(text, collapse=". ")`

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` & `tidyr` solution:

```
raw_df %>% 
    mutate(outcome = demand,
           demand = replace(demand, demand == '', NA),
           outcome = replace(outcome, outcome == '', NA),
           outcome = gsub("^cat\\d+", NA, outcome)) %>% 
    fill(demand) %>% 
    fill(outcome, .direction = "up") %>% 
    filter(!grepl("-----", text)) %>%
    group_by(demand, outcome) %>% 
    summarize(text = gsub(",", "\\.", toString(text))) %>% 
    select(text, everything())
```

- fix up the text to display as desired, swap out blanks for `NA`s, and prep the outcome column.
- `fill` the `demand` column in the default down direction, and the outcome column in an up direction.
- `filter` out the  `----- OUTCOME LINE ------` based upon its hyphens.
- generate the `group_concat` for the `text` column, and then swap the default `,` out with `.`.
- `select` the columns into the desired sequence.

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
> # Groups:   demand [2]
>                  text demand outcome
>                 <chr> <fctr>   <chr>
> 1 text1. text2. text3   cat1    info
> 2 text4. text5. text6   cat2   info2
> ```

Comment: excellent solution! very readable and taught me about `fill()` in `dplyr` as well, thanks a lot!

Comment: Great point! I let the tidyverse lines blur a bit there: `fill` is indeed a `tidyr` function. Thank you for the nudge!